# "The proxy server is refusing connections" but I'm not using a proxy?

Tags: proxy, lan, tor, cross-browser

I was using Chrome normally then saw this message `The proxy server is refusing connections` which I didn't understand what it means, so I tried a few websites then tried Firefox and also IE but none of them worked and they showed the same message. TOR browser worked perfectly, so I tried the 3 browsers again without luck, then I opened `Internet options` and found this box checked `Use a proxy server for your LAN...`  which I don't remember doing because I don't use a proxy, so I unchecked it and the internet worked again.

What can change this setting? And how to prevent it from happening again?
[image: "The proxy server is refusing connections"]

Comment: This can be a malware : http://malwaretips.com/blogs/the-proxy-server-is-refusing-connections-removal/

Comment: What does `netsh winhttp show proxy` say?

Comment: @Dan I tried it in both cases and it show the same message

`Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).`

Comment: Then, time for antivirus + malware scan

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it right now. I also opened `Internet options` again and found this local IP `127.0.0.1` written in proxy settings in both, the `HTTP` and `Secure` fields. So, maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Browsers no longer use their own proxy settings, instead they use the system ones.
For example: if you get opera 12.0, you can set its proxy independently of windows/other browsers. The system remains directly connected while Opera12 can use a proxy.
Current FF/Opera/Chrome use the windows system to set their proxy...which is very bad.
So any of them altering settings may affect all of them (+ other applications).

Comment: - The author made no mention of Opera.  The author provided screenshots of Windows network settings.  It being very bad is an opinion.  Can you better explain how this explains the behavior the author is experiencing?

Comment: I already explained. Any browser today changes the windows/system proxy settings. That change then applied to everything that is using internet connection, including other browsers. What was unclear about this ?

Comment: What isn't clear is the reason you brought up Opera.  I have seen lots of your answers mention just random information and more then not you state an opinion while doing so.

Comment: As comparison with recent ones regarding on how proxy settings were  done.

Comment: It is the way things behave, not an opinion.

Comment: I am talking about how applications setting the OSs proxy setting "is very bad" opioion comment

Comment: How is it not bad since one app changes general setting for all the others ?